# Function limits proof problem.

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Given the **Definition:** $f(n) \rightarrow a$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $n_\epsilon$ such that for all $n \geq n_\epsilon$, $|f(n) - a|\leq \epsilon.$

$\epsilon = f(n_\epsilon)$

assume $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I have to disprove that for $f(n) = \frac{n+3}{n+1}$       $f(n) \rightarrow 2$.

Keep in mind cannot assume that $f(n) \rightarrow a$ means limit of a function, so I cannot assume that if I have proved $f(n) \rightarrow 1$ is true then I know that $f(n) \rightarrow 2$ must false, because i'm pretty sure I have the proof for $f(n) \not\rightarrow 1$ is false which is an easier proof but I cannot use that here.

And I shouldn't use any mathematical concepts besides the given definition except to start my proof at a particular point. For example, If I know that $f(n) \not\rightarrow 2$ already, then I may want to start with assuming that $f(n) \rightarrow 2$ and show that it is a contradictory assumption.

This is what I have so far:

$\textit{Proof.}$ (Contradiction)

assume $f(n) \rightarrow 2$ is true.

Since $n \geq n_\epsilon, n = n_\epsilon + k,$ where $ k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Substituting into the definition:

$n_\epsilon \geq -2$ since every $\epsilon > 0$.

$|\frac{n_\epsilon + k + 3}{n_\epsilon + k + 1} - 2| \leq \frac{n_\epsilon + 3}{n_\epsilon + 1} \rightarrow [\frac{n_\epsilon + k + 3}{n_\epsilon + k + 1} - 2 \leq \frac{n_\epsilon + 3}{n_\epsilon + 1}], [2 - \frac{n_\epsilon + k + 3}{n_\epsilon + k + 1} \geq \frac{n_\epsilon + 3}{n_\epsilon + 1}]$

Simplifying the two inequalities that come from the absolute value I get:

Case 1: $0 \leq 2n_\epsilon^2 + kn_\epsilon + 4n_\epsilon + 3k + 2$

Case 2: $ 0 \geq k + 1 + 2n_\epsilon$

For Case 1:

If we let $k = 0$, then no $n_\epsilon \geq -2$ exists to fulfill this inequality (Since it must work for any $k$ as the definition states "for all $n \geq n_\epsilon$").

For Case 2:

If we let $n_\epsilon = -2$, then we have $0 \geq k -3$ which is not true for all $k$. Therefore we have a contradiction and our assumption of $f(n) \rightarrow 2$ is false.

How do I proceed with the proof? Are there any clear mistakes I made?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of $|\frac{n_\epsilon + k + 3}{n_\epsilon + k + 1} - 2| \leq \frac{n_\epsilon + 3}{n_\epsilon + 1} \rightarrow [\frac{n_\epsilon + k + 3}{n_\epsilon + k + 1} - 2 \leq \frac{n_\epsilon + 3}{n_\epsilon + 1}], [\frac{n_\epsilon + k + 3}{n_\epsilon + k + 1} - 2 \geq \frac{n_\epsilon + 3}{n_\epsilon + 1}]$?

Comment: Sorry, I was expanding the absolute value into two inequalities and I forgot to negate one side. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>2$,

$$\left|\frac{n+3}{n+1}-2\right|=1-\frac2{n+1}$$ is a strictly positive and growing function. In particular, it is never smaller than $\dfrac13$.

---

Note that the same reasoning with $L=1$ yields

$$\left|\frac{n+3}{n+1}-1\right|=\frac2{n+1}$$ which proves limit as the RHS decreases towards $0$.

Comment: Yes, I was proving that for a general case with k >= 0.

Comment: @MiteshKumar: sorry, but your proof is so complex and confuse...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler proof.

Assume that $f(n)=\frac{n+3}{n+1} \to 2$

Then for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ exists $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $|f(n)-2|<\frac{1}{2}, \forall n \geq N$ thus $f(n)>\frac{3}{2}$ for such $n$

So $1+\frac{3}{n} \geq \frac{n+3}{n+1}>\frac{3}{2}=1+\frac{1}{2}$ for every $n \geq N$

Thus $\frac{3}{n}>\frac{1}{2}, \forall n \geq N$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Is my proof correct though?

Comment: You cannot put $n_e=-2$ because $n_e$ is supposed to be a natural number

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Does everything else look good? In your solution you say $\epsilon = 1$ but that is not possible for this $f(n)$.

Comment: It does not matter if everything else looks ,good since your proof is not correct overall

Comment: I am asking if I say $n_\epsilon \geq 0$ then is it the correct approach up to case 1 and case 2?

Comment: In case 2 you cannot assume that $k+1+2n_e$ is negative because all these are positive integers

Comment: Isn't that part of the contradiction?

Comment: Then i have to say that your proof is complicated and confusing.I'm sorry.

Comment: The definition of a limit mentions $\forall \epsilon >0$ so if that limit in your post exists then for $\epsilon=1$ there is $N$ such that |.....|<1 etc...but in my post i made a typo..i wanted $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n) = \frac{n+3}{n+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{n+1}$$ and for $n \ge1$, you have

$$1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \le \frac{3}{2} <2$$

So taking $ \epsilon = 1/2$ and $n_\epsilon = 1$ solve your question.

Comment: Note $\frac{n+3}{n+1} = 1 + \frac{2}{n+1}$. You have replaced the $2$ numerator with $1$.